# Refresh ASP.NET MVC Partial View Table with server side threaded results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, timer

I have an application and I basically want to display a table in a partial view (ASP.NET MVC). This table will refresh ever 10 seconds with data from the server side. The server side data is run on a separate thread using System.Threading.Timer. Code is as follows:

Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AscomTechnicalExercise.Models.Patient>

<table id="patientsTable" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Family Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FamilyNameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Given Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.GivenNameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last Selected Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastSelectedDateSortParm })
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FamilyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GivenName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastSelectedDate)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

The following Javascript/JQuery calls back to a method to get new data every 10 seconds:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        setInterval(function () {
            $("#dvPatientListResults").hide().load('@(Url.Action("GetFullAndPartialViewModel", "PatientArea", null, Request.Url.Scheme))').fadeIn('slow');
        }, 10000);
}
```

And the method this hits looks like:

```
public ActionResult GetFullAndPartialViewModel()
{
    return PartialView("PatientList", patients);
}
```

Where patients:

```
private List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>()
{
    new Patient { ID = 0, FamilyName = "Hill", GivenName = "Chris", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now  },
    new Patient { ID = 1, FamilyName = "Stephens", GivenName = "Sion", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now },
    new Patient { ID = 2, FamilyName = "Murray", GivenName = "Thomas", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now },
    new Patient { ID = 3, FamilyName = "Dupre", GivenName = "Pierre", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now }
};
```

This patients list is updated on a separate thread every ten seconds using:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(async (e) =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        UpdatePatientsList();
    }, null, 0, 10000);
```

Where UpdatePatientList() just makes changes to the list.

However, when the clilent side refreshes every 10 seconds it does not seem to be getting the data changes from the Timer? Am I meant to merge the threads back or something? Please could some one help?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to use SignalR instead of polling. Where are the patients stored? Each controller instance is used to server a single request. Unless `patients` is loaded from cache, it will have the data assigned to it in the field initializer.

Comment: With SignalR on the other hand, you could have the timer load the new data and push it to all the clients waiting for them every 10 minutes, using web sockets. If web sockets can't be used, SignalR will fall back to polling by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... I may see if I have time to look at SignalR... I have come across it before.